# Face book Permissions error with code 200 while publishing comment to post made by users except me

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am getting Permissions error with code 200 from facebook while trying to publish a comment under post made by users other than me in the facebook fanpage whos admin is myself. I am using facebook graph api.

The exact error (JSON) is:

> {"error":{"message":"(#200) Permissions error","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

Note: the above error does not say what kind of permission required!

Detailed usecase:

1. I have a fanpage in my facebook account. I am the admin of that fan page.
2. I have registered my application in facebook with permissions including publish_stream permission. Also, I have setup `publish_stream` permission as extended permission.
3. Now, when I attempt to publish a comment under a post (to my fanpage ofcourse) made by any user other than me, I get the above permission error.

   - However, using graph API I am able to publish a comment/publish a like under a post which was made by myself either from fanpage or with graph api.
   - However, from my fanpage, I am able to comment under a post which was made by user other than me.

Note: I have a valid access token (user access token & page access token) obtained through OAuth 2.0 steps. I have got the above error when tried with both user access token and page access token.

Comment: If I use a App access token to publish comment for the above use case, I get the error: OAuthException: (#200) User must have accepted TOS

Comment: What token are you using using to post the comment? `Error 200` corresponds to a permission error. A bit of codes might help.